# RISC-V assembly on GCC - Why is a redundant mv command being generated?

Tags: riscv, riscv32

I have the following lines

```
la x14, L2
sw x13, 0(x14)
```

where the address of L2 is `0x2018`.

When I generate the ELF file and inspect it using `objdump`, this is what I see (relevant parts only):

```
...
1018: auipc   a4,0x1
101c: mv      a4,a4
1020: sw      a3,0(a4) # 2018 <L2>
...
```

The line at 1018 i.e. `mv a4 a4` translates to `addi a4, a4, 0` which is redundant. Why is this generated? Won't it still work without this line?

Does gcc have a requirement to always generate 2 instructions for the `la` instruction?

Answer (score 0):

`la` is a pseudo command for RISC-V.

See, for example, it is described in the book [RISC-V assemly language programming](https://github.com/johnwinans/rvalp/releases), chapter 4.10.2 "The la Pseudoinstruction".

Comment: Thanks, yes but what is the need to generate `mv a4, a4`? That's basically the same as a `nop`.

Comment: `mv a4, a4` is the same as `addi a4, a4, 0`. In your case, there is a relocation pointing to it so that the linker can replace the `0` with a suitable value. In case the value remains zero, the instruction is removed. This process is known as *linker relaxation*.